# Use a python module from within a package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, module, package

I have some difficulties with python module/package usage in my code. The code is here: https://github.com/cjlano/svg

```
.
└── svg
    ├── geometry.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── README.md
    ├── svg.py
    ├── svg.test.py
    └── tests
        └── [...]
```

In the module `svg` I need to use the module `geometry`. As this module did not exist in the beginning when all the code was in `svg.py`, I decided to import the entire `geometry` namespace into svg (`from geometry import *`).

My issue is that, when I import the `svg` module from my package, it works well in python2 but fails in python3:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep  6 2013, 09:59:46) 
[GCC 4.8.1 20130725 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from svg import svg
>>> help(svg)
```

Gives me access to the `svg` module documentation. Whereas

```
Python 3.3.2 (default, Sep  6 2013, 09:35:59) 
[GCC 4.8.1 20130725 (prerelease)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from svg import svg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "./svg/svg.py", line 27, in <module>
    from geometry import *
ImportError: No module named 'geometry'
```

Gives an error on import.

Any ideas on how to write my code to be usable in python3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 [doesn't do implicit relative imports any more](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PortingPythonToPy3k#relative-imports).

This means you need to either make the import of `geometry` in `svg.py` an *explicit* relative import, or [better yet](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module.htm), change it to an absolute import:

```
from svg.geometry import *
```

As pointed out by @CJlano, this then also requires `from __future__ import absolute_import` for it to still work on Python 2.

Comment: For Python2, `from __future__ import absolute_import` is required

Comment: Good catch, thank you. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It will work in both python 2.7 and 3.x if you use a relative import in `svg.py`:

```
from .geometry import *
```

Note the "." in front of the module name.

Comment: Thanks this works find but it breaks my test script `svg.test.py`: `from .geometry import *
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package` How to make everything work together?

Comment: How are you executing that file? I think you are inviting trouble by having a file with a "." in the middle of the module name (I would expect that to confuse the python import logic). Try renaming that file to something like *svg_test.py* and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Renaming does not help. I call `$ python svg_test.py` from bash command line to run my script. Python2 says `from .geometry import * ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package` and Python3 `from .geometry import * SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`, both for `import svg` and `from svg import svg` method of import in `svg_test.py`.

Comment: The problem is that you are running the file directly so the package/module hierarchy is not created (and therefore, the relative import fails). If you are at your top-level directory, this will give your error: `python svg/svg_test.py`. Whereas this will work: `python -m svg.svg_test`.

Comment: Great, it works! But I guess that is not the best strategy to write/run a small testing script... How do you write a simple test script associated with a package that can be run from within the package?

Comment: Relative module references are fine for submodule implementation (especially when you have generic module names like "geometry", "svg", etc.) but not good for test code, which should should usually emulate external client code (i.e., test code should be written from a perspective *outside* of your package's namespace. So for test modules, consider using absolute references instead (e.g., as in Lukas' answer).